# Why there is no Semigroup instance for TrieMap in scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz, semigroup

While I can do

```
Map("a" -> 1) |+| Map("a" -> 2)
```

It seems there is no support for

```
TrieMap("a" -> 1) |+| TrieMap("a" -> 2)
```

Why ?

Comment: Scalaz does not focus on support for mutable collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scalaz` doesn't provide every possible Type+Operation combination that form a Semigroup, but you can easily implement it, for instance with the following `implicit`:

```
import scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

implicit def trieMapSemigroup[K: BuildKeyConstraint, V: Semigroup]: Semigroup[TrieMap[K, V]] =
  new Semigroup[TrieMap[K, V]] {
    def append(m1: TrieMap[K, V], m2: => TrieMap[K, V]) =
      (m1 /: m2) { case (res, (k, v)) =>
        res += (k -> res.get(k).cata(Semigroup[V].append(_, v), v))
      }
  }
```

That gives you as expected:

```
scala> TrieMap("a" -> 1) |+| TrieMap("a" -> 2)
res: TrieMap(a -> 3)
```

Of course that will work for every value as semigroup that has been defined in `scalaz`.

---

### What about Monoid?

If you want an optimised version of the `implicit` that works as a Monoid too:

```
  implicit def trieMapMonoid[K: BuildKeyConstraint, V: Semigroup]: Monoid[TrieMap[K, V]] = new Monoid[TrieMap[K, V]] {
    def zero = TrieMap.empty[K, V]

    def append(m1: TrieMap[K, V], m2: => TrieMap[K, V]) = {
      val m2Instance: TrieMap[K, V] = m2
      val (from, to, semigroup) = {
        if (m1.size > m2Instance.size) (m2Instance, m1, Semigroup[V].append(_: V, _: V))
        else (m1, m2Instance, (Semigroup[V].append(_: V, _: V)).flip)
      }
      from.foldLeft(to) {
        case (res, (k, v)) => res += (k -> res.get(k).map(semigroup(_, v)).getOrElse(v))
      }
    }
  }
```

(code shameless adapted from `scalaz/std/Map.scala`)

Comment: BTW I made a presentation few months ago about semigroup in Scala that explain how to create the `implicit` on my answer. The slides are here: https://speakerdeck.com/filippovitale/will-it-blend-scalasyd-february-2015